# How to find an exact set of strings in a column of varied strings in R dataframe?

Tags: r, regex, string, dataframe, string-matching

I'm looking to find a match of an exact bunch of strings in a R dataframe column containing strings.

Here's the format in which I have my bunch of reference strings which will be stored in the variable `splitval`:

```
library(gsubfn)
#Splitting each rule into its individual parameter elements
str <- strsplit(gsub("\\,\\+"," +", gsub("=>","",  gsubfn(".", list("{" = "", "}" = ""), gsub("corpsi", "+corpsi", "{dog} => {pet}")))), split='+', fixed=TRUE)
parameters <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, str)) #Creating a df of the split parameters
parameters <- data.frame(t(parameters))
parameters <- parameters[parameters$t.parameters.!="",]
parameters <- trimws(parameters, "r")

#Applying filter on all the parameters of a single rule row
splitval = strsplit(parameters[1],split=' ', fixed=TRUE)
splitval = lapply(list(splitval[[1]]), function(z){ z[z != ""]}) #Eliminating the "" instances
```

So now, `splitval` has the following value:

```
[[1]]
[1] "dog" "pet"
```

Now my objective is to filter out all those row entries of the following dataframe where the string column's entries have both the exact words **dog** and **pet**.

Note: It should not filter out strings containing phrases like **doganimal pets** or **dogsareanimals and petssss**

This is my dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(Srno = 1:5, Description = c("dog is my pet", "doganimal pets country", "my pet is my dog", "dogsareanimals and petssss", "a pet dog is great"))
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

Hence, I need only rows 1,3 & 5 in my extract since only these contain the exclusive strings "dog" and "pet" together (in no specific order)

But when I use the following code, I get all the rows of the dataframe since all the strings contain the two keywords of reference - *grep* is not serving the intended purpose.

```
extract_df <- df[(grep(splitval[[1]][1], df$Description)),]
  for(k in 2:length(splitval[[1]]))
  {
    extract_df  <- extract_df[(grep(splitval[[1]][k], df$Description)),]
  }
```

So can anyone help me to get only rows 1,3 & 5 in the output extracted dataframe?

Comment: `df[grepl("^(?=.*\\bpet\\b)(?=.*\\dog\\b)", df$Description, perl=TRUE)]`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew is there a syntax error? It's not resulting in an empty dataframe. Though I guess I can predict the logic you're trying to use here, but I'd not like to explicitly hard-code the 2 strings of interest - I'd like to keep it in the form of variables itself, i.e. splitval[[1]][1] & splitval[[1]][2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `splitval` can have many words in it and will not always have two fixed words in it you can split string for each word and select rows that have `all` the words in `vec`.

In base R you can do this as :

```
vec <- splitval[[1]]
#For this case
#vec <- c("dog", "pet")

subset(df, sapply(strsplit(df$Description, '\\s+'), function(x) all(vec %in% x)))

#  Srno        Description
#1    1      dog is my pet
#3    3   my pet is my dog
#5    5 a pet dog is great
```

Using `tidyverse` :

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% filter(map_lgl(str_split(df$Description, '\\s+'), ~all(vec %in% .x)))
```